# how to fill inside a boundary trace?

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I have a mask of image and I have defined a boundary on this image as bellow:

[image: im1]

now I want to remove the pixels out of that boundary and get a mask like this:

[image: im2]

the boundary is a matrix of 70*2. 
and the image is 4000*3000 in size.

I can not use `imfill` in matlab as my boundary is discrete!
Do you know how I can do it in MATLAB?

Comment: [Flood fill](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flood_fill)

Answer (score 3):

You can use [`inpolygon`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/inpolygon.html) to get a mask representation of your contour.

```
% Get the X/Y Coordinates of all points in the image
[xx, yy] = meshgrid(size(img, 2), size(img, 1));

% Create a mask with 1's inside the boundary
mask = inpolygon(xx, yy, boundary(:,1), boundary(:,2))
```

If you have the Image Processing Toolbox, you can use [`poly2mask`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/poly2mask.html)

```
mask = poly2mask(boundary(:,1), boundary(:,2), size(img, 1), size(img, 2));
```

You could then use this mask to zero-out everything outside of it.

```
img = img .* mask;
```

Comment: should it be: `[xx, yy] = meshgrid(1:size(img, 1), 1:size(img, 2));
` however, using ur code and this change I made I cannot get results. it does not stop running or in other words it hangs!

Comment: @user6726469 No, the `meshgrid` inputs are always reversed. It can definitely take a while for very large images. What is the size of your image

Comment: it is 3328x4096. it takes lots of time when I change it to what I said. when I run urs it gives 0 for mask!

Comment: @user6726469 Did you try the `poly2mask` approach?

Comment: @user6726469 If it worked for you, consider marking it as a solution to help others with a similar problem